# document.exec() does not works with onchange

Tags: javascript, html

I have  function that copy a text to my clipboard, when i'm using a button for using this function with `onclick()` it's works just fine, 
The problem starts when i'm using `onchange()` on the `select` it's doesn't works at all.

**javascript**

```
function copyText(text) {
  let copyfrom = document.createElement("textarea");
  document.body.appendChild(copyfrom);
  copyfrom.textContent = text
  copyfrom.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  copyfrom.remove()
 }
```

```
    document.getElementById('copy').onclick = function() {
  copyText("Hello world");
}


document.getElementById('idToChoose').onchange = function() {
  copyText("Hello world");}
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class='modal fade' id='myModal' role='dialog'>
    <div class='modal-dialog'>
        <div class='modal-content'>
            <div class='modal-header'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal'>&times;</button>
                <h4 class='modal-title'>formats</h4>
            </div>
            <div class='modal-body'>
            <select class='form-control' id='idToChoose'>
            <option value='gradle'>gradle</option>
            <option value='ivy'>ivy</option>
            <option value='maven'>maven</option>
          </select>
                <button id='copy' type='button' class='btn btn-error' data-dismiss='modal'>copy</button>
            </div>
            <div class='modal-footer'>
                <button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>close</button></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You repeated the id twice in `document.getElementById('idToChoose')('idToChoose')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code takes the liberty of simplifying the OP's HTML to focus on getting a value from a dropdown box selection into the clipboard.

HTML:

```
<select>
  <option value="*">Please choose one</option>
    <option value="gradle">gradle</option>
          <option value="ivy">ivy</option>
          <option value="maven">maven</option>
          </select>
```

The following JavaScript as a result is simplified as well:

```
var d = document;
var val = str = "";
var s = d.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
s.onchange = function() {
  val = s.options[s.selectedIndex].value;
  if (val == "") {
    return;
  }
    else
    {
   str = "Hello " + val;
   copyText(str);
    } 
};

function copyText( text ) {
    var textArea = d.createElement("textarea");

    d.body.appendChild( textArea );

    textArea.textContent = text;
    textArea.select();

    d.execCommand("copy");  

    textArea.remove();
}
```

See [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gLn44mrq/10/)

On manually pasting from the clipboard after selecting each option, the output:

```
Hello gradle
Hello ivy
Hello maven
```

While this example code runs fine on GoogleChrome (versions 43+), apparently it is not supported by all of the primary browsers.  See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) which states:

```
copy
Copies the current selection to the clipboard. Conditions of 
having this behavior enabled vary from one browser to another,
and have evolved over time. Check the compatibility table to 
determine if you can use it in your case.
```

Comment: not working, the problem is to exec in onchange i think

Comment: @Daniel Taub: Please see my revised code and the quote from the MDN.

Comment: Note that the onchange event attribute becomes viable because I added a "Please choose one" option before the the three format types.  So, when the user selects any of those three options, an onchange event occurs for the dropdown box.

Comment: Yes, it does.  Try modifying your HTML and have a "Please Choose" option.  Then when you select one of the format options it should work for you, too. Here's a "fiddle" that demos that point: https://jsfiddle.net/L9f5j9v8/9/

Comment: The onchange works , but the exec option not working

Comment: It's shows that copy should work for me , but it doesn't

Comment: Here's something else that may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33321095/cannot-use-document-execcommandcopy-from-developer-console

Answer (score 2):

This

```
document.getElementsByTagName('idToChoose')
```

Should be changed to

```
document.querySelector('#idToChoose')
```

Comment: I've changed , but it still don't works, the problem is something with the onchange() function

Comment: If you changed in this way this is still wrong:
document.getElementById('idToChoose')('idToChoose')

This should be:
document.getElementById('idToChoose')

Comment: what do you mean works, it's supposed to copy the text to the clipboard and it's not working...

Comment: it copies the text you pass in the function onchange. It does. If you try to paste it it will paste hello world correctly.

Comment: Tried from different devices and browsers still not working

Comment: Open the jsfiddle. Change the value in the select. Paste in notepad. You see the hello world. Is this not happening to you? Which browser are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
document.getElementsByTagName('idToChoose')
```

with

```
document.getElementsByTagName('select')
```

or

```
document.getElementById('idToChoose')
```

`getElementsByTagName` does not work with id values. You have to use the tag. Also, id is always unique, which is why `getElementById` returns only one element.

Comment: I've changed , but it still don't works, the problem is something with the onchange() function

Comment: my bad, but it's still not working, the exec() with onchange is the problem i think

Comment: you are sending static text so the event should not matter at least for now

Comment: the closing `}` is missing, or is that just here?

Comment: and the select element is not inside a form, that can cause problems.

Comment: In my code it's good , I didn't copy it good , Iva debugging the code and it's just doesn't works

Comment: did you try adding form tags?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144205/discussion-between-daniel-taub-and-inarilo).